Relationship between $L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ and $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ norms
We need to show neither inclusion $L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{d}) \subset L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ nor the opposite inclusion hold. By definition, I  think I need to find funtions $f$ and $g$ such that the $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} |f| < \infty$, but $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} |f|^{2} \nless \infty$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} |g|^{2} <\infty$ but $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} |g| \nless \infty$. How do I do that?

first try with $d=1$ and test function like $1/x^a$ and then generalize
